# CoffeeScript / JavaScript - Making promises compatible with Source Maps?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, q, source-maps

source maps are making it really easy to debug CoffeeScript code within the browser. Can't live without it now!

I'm using Q for promises and unfortunately Q returns the raw trace stack when an error is raised within a promise.

```
Q.when $.ajax(...)
.then ()->
   ...
.fail (error)->
   console.log error.stack
```

---

Is there a way to transform the default stack trace in it's "source mapped" counter part?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Source maps aren't really very suited to this, but with the V8 JavaScript engine (used in Google Chrome and node.js) it is possible to mutate the stack trace using the JavaScript API.

Q will do this if you enable long stack traces.  You should not use it in production though as it comes with an enormous performance hit: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#long-stack-traces

Comment: Yes I've looked into that, unfortunately no way to get source maps to work in this scenario.

Comment: The issue is, what would source maps mean in the context of this?  soure maps don't influence the flow of code, just the location of it.  I can see something more being done with generators, when combined with promises, but it wouldn't be source maps.